# Tool for sql refactoring?

Tags: sql, refactoring

Is there a refactoring tool available for SQL (TSQL in particular).  Is there any tool that can do automatic simplification of SQL?

I have a set of views where only the top two are used, and I'd like to refactor this into only two views, hence 10+ queries into two queries.

Answer (score 5):

Try [ApexSQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx)

ApexSQL Refactor is a FREE SSMS and VS add-in, for formatting SQL statements using nearly 200 formatting options and 11 code refactors. It expands wildcards, qualifies object names, renames SQL database objects and parameters without breaking dependencies, encapsulates code as a stored procedure, scalar function, table function, and view, add surrogate keys and more

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Comment: awesome, this should get more upvotes

Answer (score 3):

Red-Gate Software has a tool called [SQL Refactor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm) which should do what you're looking for.

*Update.* as BlueRaja correctly states - SQL Refactor has been discontinued as a separate product, and its functionality is now integrated into [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) (which is a **great tool** in itself, and well worth the money for its license!)

Comment: SQL Refactor has now been replaced by [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/)

Answer (score 1):

+1 to marc_s which I suspect is what you're after. Just to add, the only other tool I know of that automatically refactors SQL is [Toad for SQL Server](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-sql-server/) by Quest Software. Feature list is [here](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-sql-server/configurations-checklist.aspx).

I've never used it, so don't exactly know what it does but thought it worth a mention.